# Classification NN stuck some point and changing initializers and optimizers doesn't really help in increasing accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural net to predict if if certain signal is PN, NN, NP or PP based on some values.
Each sample in main dataset (before spliting it in training, valid and test datasets) has these values:

```
df[['SIGNAL_CLASS1', 'SIGNAL_CLASS2', 'value1', 'value2[-2]', 'value2[-1]', 'value3[-2]', 'value3[-1]', 'value4[-2]', 'value4[-1]', 'value5[-2]', 'value5[-1]', 'value6[-2]', 'value6[-1]', 'PN', 'NN', 'PP', 'NP']]
```

Where 'PN', 'NN', 'PP', 'NP' are classes - characteristics the neural network will try to predict from this data.

Unfortunately I have a problem with the amount of data, I have only around 800 entries, and I would have to wait another month to double it.

For example two of many figures of the data looks like this:
[image]
[image]

So as you can see, each class create clusters which should be pretty easy to recognise by DL algorithm.

And my model is implemented like this:

```
initializer = keras.initializers.he_normal
initializer2 = keras.initializers.glorot_normal
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have tried, NAdam, SGD and ADAM, while Adam with configuration as above returned the best results.
After 6000 epochs the NN started to overfit data.
With NAdam and SGD while loss was lower (it dropped up to 0.5 from 1.6(in comparison to Adam)) the accuracy metric was performing worse by factor of around 0.1 - in this study I need accuracy to be as high as possible.

What can I do to improve this algorithm to improve both loss value and accuracy?

**Accuracy metric from the best performing model:**

[image]

**Loss metrics from the best performing model:**

[image]

**Value of prediction of the last 3 data entries, each is correct:**

```
[[3.8021428e-03 1.2107183e-02 8.2946038e-01 1.5463033e-01]
[2.9745519e-01 7.0145488e-01 4.8669678e-04 6.0323032e-04]
[3.5228598e-04 1.1418171e-03 8.0789638e-01 1.9060946e-01]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `neural nets` i'd recommend first creating clusters as features and then applying a traditional classification algorithm. After clustering you may even be able to just use a `support vector machine` classifier [scikit-learn support vector machine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

Comment: tell me if I understand it right, by clusters as features you meant that I have to feed my data to clustering algorithm, that will output x clusters that are composed of my data points, and then use an ordinary classification algorithm on this output?

Comment: I am recommending to include the clusters as _one_ of the features: your classification will depend on [potentially many] other features as well.